# htaccess rewrite url for laravel project to exclude folder directory from url

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have instaledl ubuntu 16.04 server and I have lots of laravel projects in
/var/www/html with numeric folder like below:

```
<pre>
    121744
       content
         app
         bootstrap
         config
         database
         public
         resources
         routes
         storage
         tests
         vendor
         composer.json
         composer.lock
         server.php   
         ....
</pre>


<pre>
    12877
       content
         app
         bootstrap
         config
         database
         public
         resources
         routes
         storage
         tests
         vendor
         composer.json
         composer.lock
         server.php   
         ....
</pre>

<pre>
    8798
       content
         app
         bootstrap
         config
         database
         public
         resources
         routes
         storage
         tests
         vendor
         composer.json
         composer.lock
         server.php   
         ....
</pre>
```

As per above folder to open laravel application in the browser the url look like below:

```
http://example.com/121744/content/public

http://example.com/12877/content/public

http://example.com/8798/content/public
```

The content in the url is common.
I want to remove content from url so that the url should look like below:

```
http://example.com/121744/public

http://example.com/12877/public

http://example.com/8798/public
```

The location of .htaccess file in `var/www/html/.htaccess`.

Please help me, how do I make htaccess do this?

Comment: Not sure if this is just your terminology, but you don't use `.htaccess` to "remove `content` from the URL" like this. You need to actually change the URLs in your application to remove `content` from the links themselves - have you already done this? You would then use `.htaccess` for the 2nd part, to internally rewrite the URL that does _not_ contain `content` to add it back again so the URL "works". (Only if you've already changed the URL structure and you need to preserve SEO would you consider actually "removing" `content` from the URL using `.htaccess`.)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/content/([\w-]+)/?$ /$1/$2 [NC,L]
```

In case your `public` directory is fixed each time then try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/content/(public)/?$ /$1/$2 [NC,L]
```